# Order matters when using all.equal(x,y) vs all.equal(y,x): Potantial infinite recursion?

Tags: r, recursion, object-comparison

I was trying to test equality of different R Objects and found that sometimes, when comparing objects in the wrong order, following error is occurring:

> Error: C stack usage  7975620 is too close to the limit

Am I right that this is a Sign of too deep recursion?

It should be reproducible by following comparisons:

```
all.equal(mean, sd) # no error
all.equal(sd,mean) # Error: C stack usage 7975620 is too close to the limit
all.equal(NULL, mean) # no error
all.equal(mean,NULL) # Error: C stack usage 7975620 is too close to the limit 
all.equal(mean, sum); all.equal(sd, sum) # no Error
all.equal(sum,NULL) # no error
all.equal(sd, var) # no error
all.equal(var, mean) # Error: C stack usage 7975620 is too close to the limit
all.equal(var, NULL)  # Error: C stack usage 7975620 is too close to the limit
```

I am aware that the methods/functions I compared are implemented quite differently in R and there seems to be a pattern in comparison failure depending on how a given method is implemented, however I am wondering whether the behavior of the function is intended as such (I couldnt find a note on the order of objects to be compared within the documentation). I am also curious about it and would very appreciate if someone could explain this behavior to me.

I could also reproduce these issues within R --vanilla when from the terminal.

Session Info:

> R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10) Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit) Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
>
> Matrix products: default BLAS:
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0 LAPACK:
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0
>
> locale:  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
> [3] LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8      [5]
> LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8     [7]
> LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                   [9]
> LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             [11]
> LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
> datasets  methods   base
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] compiler_4.1.3

Edit: Tried the code samples on Rstudio Server and could NOT reproduce above behavior. Outputs of all.equal Function also differ

Session Info:

> R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10) Platform: x86_64-suse-linux-gnu (64-bit)
> Running under: openSUSE Leap 15.2
>
> Matrix products: default BLAS:   /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so LAPACK:
> /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so
>
> locale:  [1] LC_CTYPE=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
> LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=de_DE.UTF-8
> LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8     [6] LC_MESSAGES=de_DE.UTF-8
> LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C
> LC_TELEPHONE=C             [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
> LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
> datasets  methods   base
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] compiler_4.0.3
> tools_4.0.3

Comment: Share your `sessionInfo()`. I am getting `"target, current do not match when deparsed"`
when I run `all.equal(mean, sd)` or `all.equal(sd,mean)` I am using `R version 4.0.2 `

Comment: Just updated my Question with the session info. Your output would be the one I expected!. However when running `all.equal(mean, sd)` I get a very extensive list of mismatches (more than 1000 outputs)

Comment: On Windows 11 I am also getting a very extensive list of mismatches, 2837. But when running `all.equal(sd,mean)` both Rstudio and Rscript hang.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I followed the error for `all.equal(sd,mean)`, it actually stems from the call `all.equal.environment(environment(sd), environment(mean), ignore.environment = FALSE)`.

From the documentation of `all.equal()`, we see that the environment method has the extra argument `evaluate` which is a

> logical indicating if “promises should be forced”

This defaults to true, and seems to cause the stack usage problem.

To fix it, just call `all.equal(..., evaluate = FALSE)`:

```r
all.equal(mean, sd, evaluate = FALSE)
#> [1] "target, current do not match when deparsed"                                                                                                   
#> [2] "names of environments differ: Lengths (1370, 1134) differ (string compare on first 1134) names of environments differ: 1134 string mismatches"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

#### Results:

```r
all.equal(mean, sd, evaluate = FALSE) # no Error
all.equal(sd,mean, evaluate = FALSE) # no Error
all.equal(NULL, mean, evaluate = FALSE) # no Error
all.equal(mean,NULL, evaluate = FALSE) # no Error
all.equal(mean, sum, evaluate = FALSE) # no Error
all.equal(sum,NULL, evaluate = FALSE) # no Error
all.equal(sd, var, evaluate = FALSE) # no Error
all.equal(var, mean, evaluate = FALSE) # no Error
all.equal(var, NULL, evaluate = FALSE)  # no Error
```

Comment: Thank You! This solves my Problem. Also, the argument `check.environment = FALSE` prevents the c stack error. Could you also explain why the order of the objects matter and do you know whether this is intended?

Comment: Yes, `check.environment = FALSE` makes sure that `all.equal.environment` is not run at all, and thus you never get the problem. It's an easy solution if you don't need to compare the environments at all.

Comment: A bit simplified: When you run `all.equal()` on two functions with `check.environment = TRUE`, `all.equal()` will check if environments are the same. This means that it will see if the `base` package contains the same  functions as the `stats` package. When `evaluate` is also TRUE, R loops through the `n` first functions in both packages and compare them with `all.equal` (recursion, as you suspected). `n` is here the number of function in the package from where your first function is from - thus the order of the arguments matter.

Comment: Since `base` has more functions than `stats`, this leads to more recursive calls, and thus the stack problem. Please let me know if I should update my answer with any of this information.

Comment: No need for updating your Answer, Thanks a lot for your effort! I appreciate it a lot